# Webpack generating the url of another file for CSS url()

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack to compile and develop my Drupal theme using Bootstrap 4. I use it to bundle different JS libraries and to build my sass into CSS so I can use only the elements of Bootstrap that I need instead of the whole shebang.

I have a source folder with a "js" folder and a "sass" folder.

My webpack.config.json looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [ './src/js/bootstrap.js', './src/sass/style.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: 'js/mytheme-libraries.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.')
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader', // load files
          options: {
            name: 'style.css',
            outputPath: './css',
          },
        },
        {loader: 'extract-loader'},
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            plugins: function () {
              return [
                require('autoprefixer')
              ];
            },
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapEmbed: false
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapEmbed: false,
            outFile: './css/style.map.css'
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/fonts")
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '/sites/all/themes/mytheme/fonts/[name].[ext]',
            emitFile: false
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/fonts")
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '/sites/all/themes/mytheme/img/[name].[ext]',
            emitFile: false
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

and my package.json

```
{
    "name": "mytheme",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Tools for building Bootstrap for the Mytheme Theme.",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build-dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
        "cache-clear": "drush @dev cc all"
    },
    "author": "Pryrios",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "animated-scroll-to": "^1.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
        "extract-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
        "webpack": "^4.41.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
    }
}
```

and I build my assets by running "npm run build-dev" which calls "webpack --config webpack.config.js" and builds my style.css and my js file. (Note: I am not emitting the image/font files as they are already on the folder inside the theme I am building and are referenced from the src/sass folder by "../..").

Now in one of my CSS files I am using the same background image twice:

```css
.myfirst-div {
  background: url('../../img/point-bg.png') center 5px/2px 10px repeat-y;
}

.mysecond-div {
  background: url("../../img/point-bg.png") center 5px/2px 10px repeat-y;
}
```

The expected result is to have both CSS declarations like:

```css
.myfirst-div {
  background: url('/sites/all/themes/mytheme/img/point-bg.png') center 5px/2px 10px repeat-y;
}

.mysecond-div {
  background: url("/sites/all/themes/mytheme/img/point-bg.png") center 5px/2px 10px repeat-y;
}
```

**The issue:**

But what I find is that the second div has a different image. The path is correct and the image exists but it is not the one declared on the sass. I have investigated and the image that is being returned is the next one declared in "url()" in the sass.

I don't understand why this is happening. I am quite new to this whole webpack/nodejs environment so I may be doing many things wrong. I've tried using --profile when invoking webpack to try to check anything wrong but to no avail.

¿Can anyone point me where am I screwing?¿Or at least suggest how can I debug further this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with my problem is due to extract-loader:

https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader/issues/54

In short: extract-loader is not respecting the interpolation of files in css-loader output which results in inconsistencies on the final urls.

As it seems it won't be solved soon (or at all), I've moved on to mini-css-extract-plugin which replaces extract-loader + file-loader.

My webpack config now looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: [ './src/js/bootstrap.js', './src/sass/style.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: 'js/bitbrain-libraries.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.')
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: "jQuery"
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/style.css',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use:[{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
        }, {
          loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run postcss actions
          options: {
            plugins: function () { // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
              return [
                require('autoprefixer')
              ];
            },
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            outFile: './css/style.map.css'
          } // compiles Sass to CSS
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/fonts")
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '/sites/all/themes/bitbrain/fonts/[name].[ext]',
            emitFile: false
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/fonts")
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '/sites/all/themes/bitbrain/img/[name].[ext]',
            emitFile: false
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The important parts are:

1- Installing Mini CSS Extract Loader:

```
npm install --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin)
```

2- Requiring the plugin with

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
```

3- Declaring it on the configuration and using it on modules:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',

  ...

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/style.css',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use:[{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
        }, 

        ...

      },
    ]
  }
};
```